# AngularJS UI Bootstrap 0.6.0 Modal with Module.Controller() syntax

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Instead of defining the controller for my modal instance like this:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) { /*ctrl-code-here*/ };
```

I want to define it using Module.Controller() syntax:

```
angular.module('MyModule', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'items', function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $modalInstance, items) { /*ctrl-code-here*/ }])
    .controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', function ModalDemoCtrl($scope, $modal, $log) {
        $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

        $scope.open = function() {

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,  //what do I put here to reference the other controller?
                resolve: {
                    items: function() {
                        return $scope.items;
                    }
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
                $scope.selected = selectedItem;
            }, function() {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        };
    }]);
```

In $modal.open, how do I reference ModalInstanceCtrl correctly?

Comment: You put it in quotes.

Comment: I had the same problem: Argh is it really that simple? @Stewie did you knew this out of experience or where should i have been able to find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put it in quotes, like this `controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',`

Here is an example based on the demo in angular-ui bootstrap

http://plnkr.co/edit/Xa6KqUCew9OTrtEQYjku?p=preview

Comment: Snap, sometimes the simplest solutions are the most difficult ones. Thanks for pointing out also my oversight.... Hello unit testable controller!

Comment: lost 3 hours of my life because of this. I wanna stab someone!